# DB2 Error: sql10007n message "-1032" could not be retrieved. reason code: "5"

Tags: database, db2, websphere, ibm-cloud, db2-luw

I get the following error when trying to connect to a db2 db(IBM Db2 community edition version 11.5.0.0. Windows 10 operating system, I am Administrator.)

`SQL10007N Message "-1390" could not be retrieved.  Reason code: "5".`

However, I could able to create an instance but when I type `db2 get instance` I get the above error.

Comment: Db2 community edition version 11.5.0.0.  Windows 10 operating system, I am Administrator.

Comment: The value of the environment variable DB2INSTANCE is either invalid, or the variable is not set.  Typically on MS-Windows its value by default is DB2.  Are you running in a container or a virtual-machine? Check the account (in `services.msc`used for running the Db2 services.

Comment: The meaning of code -1390 is shown in previous comment. The meaning of code -1032 is `db2start` has not yet run or not yet completed.  Did you install the product correctly without errors? Did you run the GUI for First-Steps following installation?

Comment: Yes I installed it with no errors but following the installation when I create a sample database, it says "Attempt to start DB2 instance failed
  'db2sampl' processing complete." what should I need to do? Can you please guide me?

Comment: @Shrishibi Do you run `db2sampl` from `Start -> Run -> db2cwadmin.bat`? If yes, then, please, edit your question with the contents of `db2diag_3m.txt` file appeared in the current directory after `db2diag -H 3m -o db2diag_3m.txt` (all the db2 diagnostic log entries for the last 3 minutes) being run immediately after a failed `db2sampl` attempt.

Comment: I had this same error after setting my "Language for non-Unicode programs" (i.e. Locale) under "Administrative Language Settings" to "Beta: Use Unicode-UTF8 for worldwide language support". Removing that setting and rebooting resolved the issue.